# adding footer/header to base64 encoded string

Tags: java, base64, x509certificate, bouncycastle

So I have an X509Certificate that I encode like this

```java
String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(certificate.getEncoded());
```

But this returns a string that looks like this (MII....)
Hence why I believe that when I run this part

```java
PEMParser reader= new PEMParser (new StringReader(new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64))));
PemObject object = reader.readPemObject();
```

The `object` is equal to null.
I believe that this is because the base64 encoded string is missing the header/footer `-----BEGIN CERTIFCATE-----` and `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.

any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The PEM encoding is derived from the DER encoding by first Base64 encoding the DER data with a line break after every 64 characters and adding a specific header and footer line.
Although this can be easily implemented, BouncyCastle provides convenient support for converting DER to PEM and vice versa. For writing PEM data [`JcaPEMWriter`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/jcajce/JcaPEMWriter.html) is used, for parsing PEM data [`PEMParser`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/openssl/PEMParser.html).
This applies not only to certificates, but also to public and private keys of various formats (PKCS#8, X.509/SPKI, PKCS#1).

The current question is about the conversion of a certificate. In this case the header line is `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and the footer line is `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`. The following example shows the use of both classes for the conversion PEM to DER and DER to PEM:

```java
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Base64;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMWriter;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObjectGenerator;

...

// PEM encoded certificate
String cert = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
        + "MIIFlTCCA32gAwIBAgIJAO4YFLMMLNM2MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMGExCzAJBgNV\r\n"
        ...
        + "nZSJxV3jloZP3NJDIQOZ8zXBqzVfba9fOOZF1ghIa0wFuvH1Ip1vL1sdBdo4PFsY\r\n"
        + "BQfFgCihe1CeDfY3gNQVQSS/dQ5139+kBQBsYnEeWoz0CLQWhGp3B/8=\r\n"
        + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

// Convert PEM to DER
PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new StringReader(cert));
PemObject pemObject = pemParser.readPemObject(); 
byte[] derCertificate = pemObject.getContent(); // the DER encoded certificate
System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(derCertificate));

// Convert DER to PEM
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
JcaPEMWriter jcaPEMWriter = new JcaPEMWriter(stringWriter);
jcaPEMWriter.writeObject((PemObjectGenerator)new PemObject("CERTIFICATE", pemObject.getContent()));
jcaPEMWriter.close();
String pemCertificate = stringWriter.toString(); // the PEM encoded certificate
System.out.println(pemCertificate);
```

The code requires the bcprov and bcpkix jar files.

Similarly, private and public keys can be converted, with only the `CERTIFICATE` string in the `PemObject` constructor needing to be adjusted:

```
format                  string
---------------------------------------
PKCS#8                  PRIVATE KEY
X.509/SPKI              PUBLIC KEY
PKCS#1, private         RSA PRIVATE KEY
PKCS#1, public          RSA PUBLIC KEY
```